error: Failed due to error: bunsh: No such file or directory running bun dev
So, I moved on to windows today, i installed Bun, but when I run the script bun dev it says:
error: Failed due to error: bunsh: No such file or directory.
The weird thing is that when i run the same command in terminal, it works.
This is everything I have in my package.json file:
{
  
"name": "app",
  
"version": "1.0.50",
  
"scripts": {

    "dev": "bun --watch run src/index.ts"

  },

 "module": "src/index.js"

}

I already tried to add a ./ in the src/index.ts, I entred into the src directory to run with just the index.ts in the script and didn't work either.

Maybe the problem is that your script config calls it src/index.ts and the script is perhaps actually named src/index.js

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Not sure if it applies to you but I had encountered the same error today. Turns out it was because my project folder name contained Chinese characters, after I changed the folder name to English it works.
Otherwise you could first try the npm/node version to see if it works and if not node might provide a bit more info. In my case npm works but bun doesn't so it was some kind of bug.

Same problem here, buddy. Running Windows 11 and bun 1.1.4;
I can run bun normally, as long as im not asking it to run a script from package.json. It just works as expected. I can even run the scripts manually using bun and it will work. NPM run works perfectly with the same scripts as well. But just as soon as i do "bun dev", it throws me the following error:
command i run:
bun dev
response i get:
$ cd sisref-v2-dashboard-client; bun dev
error: Failed due to error: bunsh: No such file or directory:
This is my package.json, in case anyone can help:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@microsoft/eslint-formatter-sarif": "2.1.7",
    "@mui/base": "^5.0.0-beta.40",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.57.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "next": "^14.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "slide-element": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "name": "sisref-v2-dashboard",
  "module": "index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^19.2.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^19.1.0",
    "@eslint/js": "^8.57.0",
    "@types/bun": "latest",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "globals": "^15.0.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.7.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "cm": "cz",
    "dev": "cd sisref-v2-dashboard-client; bun dev",
    "lint": "bun eslint ./sisref-v2-dashboard-client/src/ --fix",
    "lint-ci": "npx eslint ./sisref-v2-dashboard-client/src/ --format @microsoft/eslint-formatter-sarif > eslint-results.sarif"
  }
}


Apparently this is happening in the latest version for Windows users.
You can run your project using npm run dev until the issue is fixed.
